# php. Include txt file that contains select box. Then get part of the select box (part of string)

Tags: php

For example, I have text file `1.txt` with content like this

```
<span id="1" class="locations_div">
<select name="loc_lev_one" id="loc_lev_one" class="location" >
<option value="blank">Select</option>
<option value="1">London</option>
<option value="2">Bristol</option>
</select> 
</span>
```

I include the text file `include('1.txt');`

As result see html select box.

But want to see part of select box code (as string).

Tried `echo substr( ( include('1.txt') ), 10 );`

But see the same/initial select bow.

How to get part of code of text file?

Tried

`echo substr( ( file_get_contents( '1.txt' ) ), 100 );` and see as string.

So appears, that in this situation instead of `include` just need to use `file_get_contents`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `include()` like this:

```
ob_start();
?>
include "1.txt";
<?php
$str = ob_get_clean();
echo(substr($str, 10));
```

But the function `file_get_contents()` is much better.

Comment: how do the ob_ functions work in this context? Never really got why use these functions or how they are useful.

Comment: this is an output accumulator concept.